# Saving vector layer with another coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I want to save vector layer with another coordinate system but i still want to have this layer on the same place.

I created layer on the area with not correct coordinate system and after updating to arcgis it is rotated. I want to create new layer (the same polygons) with correct coordinate system on the same place. There is too much work with creating new layer with new coordinates.

Is there posibility to do that what im asking for?

Answer (score 1):

The [Project](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm) tool (Arc Toolbox >> Data Management >> Projections and Transformations >> Project) projects spatial data from one coordinate system to another.

If by "on the same place" you mean having the same file path, just save over your existing "layer" (i.e. feature class) in the same .gdb.